# OpenVPN routes my web traffic, but not outbound SSH traffic?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I just set up a new OpenVPN server following Digital Ocean's guide, and so far for the most part, things are going well. When I visit ipchicken.com or any other IP site, it shows the IP address of the VPN that I'm connected to.

However, I wanted to set up ssh firewall rules to only allow access to itself if the source IP address is *itself*. I'm not able to achieve this because I can still see that when I initiate the SSH connections, it shows the last IP address came from my home IP address and not the VPN's IP.

So essentially, I want it to be required for me to connect to the VPN, and then SSH is accessible. It seems that I might have to do something a little crazy with the routes in order to accomplish this -- not sure. When I set up the firewall rules on other systems to require the VPN gateway's IP prior to allowing SSH, it works perfectly fine. For whatever reason, SSH'ing into the VPN gateway itself always seem to recognize that I'm coming from an IP address other than itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The most probably reason is simply that you **need** a route to the VPN server to communicate with it. When you ssh the same host, the same route is applied. I would not care about that; ssh is encrypted and secure. What happens if you ssh a different host?

Comment: @vidarlo if i SSH into another host, that host shows me coming from the VPN IP address which is exactly what I want. I just didn't want to leave SSH exposed to the Internet especially if I had a nice and secure VPN solution in place. any other thoughts on that by chance?

Comment: SSH is no more or less secure than OpenVPN if you use both diligently with key files etc. I see no reason to expose one but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just didn't want to leave SSH exposed to the Internet especially if I had a nice and secure VPN solution in place. any other thoughts on that by chance?

Two choices - change where ssh listens, or firewall:

### Change how sshd listens

Yes. Set ssh not to listen on the public address, but only on the VPN address.

If you run `sudo editor /etc/ssh/sshd_config` you'll see two lines defining this:

```
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

They are commented out, and the default is to listen to all interfaces. To restrict it, simply add a line like so:

```
ListenAddress 10.1.2.3
```

The IP should be the IP defined for your VPN interface. Restart sshd with `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

### Firewall

Add a firewall rule that drops ssh on your public interface:

```
sudo ufw deny in on eno0 to any port 22 proto tcp
```

This will drop ssh on interface `eno0`

In either case you will not be able to ssh to the public IP anymore, but you'll have to use the one defined for the VPN interface.

The reason you see this behavior is that the VPN clients needs to talk to the VPN server. It therefor adds a route against that single host via your networks gateway, before it replaces the route. SSH will, of course, use the same route.

Note that I would not do this at all. If VPN stops working, you'll be locked out of ssh access. Further, ssh is *made* to be secure. It's supposed to be used over the public internet. If you set it up with key based authentication, and disallow password authentication, it's basically as good authentication as a VPN solution.

Comment: Listening on just the VPN interface did the trick. Thanks a lot!!