# Can't access web servers from outside network after server connects to vpn

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

So I have Ubuntu 18.04 server installed with several docker's running different Web applications for example (plex). I have port forwarding setup and I can connect to all web apps just fine on network and outside network. My problem is once I setup openvpn on the host the dockers are running on all outside access is blocked to the server. I know this is probably something simple that I am missing. If you need any information from files I will gladly post if needed.

Also OpenVPN is setup as a service to start on boot up.

Thanks

Edit1

Here are my routes VPN on:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.21.92.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
x.x.x.x         10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       172.21.92.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4437e
172.21.92.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
205.185.198.207 10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

x.x.x.x is external IP 10.0.0.1 Gateway

Off VPN:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
x.x.x.x         10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4437e5faff27
```

Comment: Can you connect to the web services from inside network when the openvpn is running?

Comment: This is likely to happen, since your default route in VPN.  Connections are receiving packets from your WAN ip, but it will try to send all response packets through VPN gateway, which will definitely not work.  You need to adjust routing.

Comment: User68186: yes I can connect to them from within the network.
Alvin Laing: thank you for your response I had suspicions that is the VPN causing the problem how do I go about adjusting the routing I’m new to setting up a VPN on the Linux server this way.

Comment: Could I get an example on how I should go about this?

Comment: @AlvinLiang consider converting your comment to a full answer. I am not familiar with IP routing and IPtables to provide a solution.

Comment: I found some other questions and answer that may help you find a solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/649792/prevent-ssh-connection-lost-after-logging-into-vpn-on-server-machine/747828 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037344/openvpn-routes-my-web-traffic-but-not-outbound-ssh-traffic these are about `ssh` but the same principle may apply towards docker connections.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for the links and trying to help with a problem you are not familiar with. I did try adding a route from external IP to default gateway as was suggested in the first link but that did not work either.

Comment: First, please edit the original question and add the new information on the question. Second, please don't put screenshots of text. Rather copy and paste from terminal to the edit question window. Then highlight the pasted text and format as code using the { } icon above the edit question window. This will help those trying to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Deleted comment and added to original question.

Comment: I do have a full answer yet, because the question is that what you try to  achieve.  Using VPN to redirect all outgoing traffic and having a service on the WAN at the same time is a bit contradictive.  If the VPN is only for a remote office, and the remote office only has 172.21.92.0/23 IP range, then 0.0.0.0 via 172.21.92.1 and 128.0.0.0 via 172.21.92.1 routing rules are not needed.  Try remove them first.

Comment: I do need all traffic from the dockers going through the vpn with the exception of 1-2 of the dockers. Is it possible to route traffic from 1-2 dockers outside of the vpn and keep the rest within? I was trying to keep everything within one server for simplicity. But I'm getting the feeling I may need to move the 1-2 dockers to another server. I would like to learn the way to fix the setup if there is one instead of working around it.